# How can I access an element (of a custom component) by its 'id' within its parent? (ReactJS.Net)

Tags: reactjs.net

I expect the following is excessively easy, which probably plays into why I've had trouble finding the solution on the web:

I would like to reference elements made from my custom components by there IDs using document.getElementById("id") from within a parent component.

I have created a couple of react components, one of which includes the other in the render function. I have given the inner element (I will refer to this as 'c1', and the outer as 'c0') an id="myID", and I would like to reference it using `document.getElementById("myID").myValue`. However, whenever I try to access it this way, I receive the error message `TypeError: Unable to get property 'myValue' of undefined or null reference`. C1 does have a property 'myValue', although I don't think that should matter to this particular error.

This effectively the pair of components, simplified to the relevant parts:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {c1} from './c1.js';

export class c0 extends Component
{
    displayName = c0.name

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testValue: ""
        }
    {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setState({
            testValue: document.getElementById("myID").id
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="testID">
                <c1 id="myID" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class c1 extends Component
{
    displayName = c1.name

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Here is some content</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

To be clear, c1 *is rendering* from within c2. I just can't access it from the document for some reason.

My searches have basically resulted in non-reactjs, explanations for what is "better" than using `document.getElementById()`, and questions that assume I've already gotten this far. The last is understandable, but not very helpful to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Upon further inspection, the component seems to render exclusively as the set of html elements it contains. In the sample provided, `document.getElementById("testID").firstChild` returns `HTMLDivElement`. Specifically, it returns whichever HTMLElement is outermost in c1's `render()` function. I assume this is normal to some degree, but I wouldn't know for sure. Directly accessing by 'id' still returns null.

Comment: You probably already checked this but is that component and it's ID unique?
Because if it isn't you'll have the same id twice in whatever you're trying to render.

Comment: Yeah, the id is unique. I double-checked. That's a good thing to keep an eye out for, though - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Having given an id of "testID" to the 'div' surrounding the instance of c1, `document.getElementById("testID").firstChild` returns `HTMLDivElement`, while `document.getElementById("myID")` returns `null`. (This isn't sufficient, unfortunately.)

Comment: @KevinJohnson (I suppose I ought to let you know I've responded, whoops.)

Comment: one last thing to verify would be that the id is actually passed to c1. 
If you got a div element back when you queried that parent DIV, verify that the childs ID was actually set
I'm guessing the ID passed into c1 from c2 is actually just being ignored during the instantiation and it actually needs to be an explicit parameter as it isn't explicitly set in the templates render function or constructor while the "testID" is .

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to find a workable solution. However, the following may not be sufficient for all users, so bear that in mind.

Within the `render` function of c1, I assigned the outermost `<div>` the same id as c1 itself, like so:

`<div id={this.props.id}>`.

It feels a bit patchwork, but it does the job. From this point, the properties of c1 can be changed or accessed when necessary, so long as those properties have also been assigned to that outermost `<div>`.